# Angular 15 Mat Menu error : Class constructor Boolean cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular15

I migrated an Angular App from Angular 13 to Angular 15, and I have issues using MatMenu which was working properly before.

Even if I use the default example in the Angular Material website, it doesn't work and trigger an error in the console each time I click on the menu button. Here is a simple demo code that is not working :

```html
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
    <span>Redial</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item disabled>
    <mat-icon>voicemail</mat-icon>
    <span>Check voice mail</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
    <span>Disable alerts</span>
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

And here is the error displayed in the console :

```
core.mjs:8453 ERROR TypeError: Class constructor Boolean cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at NgClass.ngDoCheck (vendor.js:62561:34)
    at callHook (vendor.js:72247:12)
    at callHooks (vendor.js:72212:9)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (vendor.js:72169:5)
    at refreshView (vendor.js:79857:11)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (vendor.js:80812:9)
    at refreshView (vendor.js:79866:5)
    at refreshComponent (vendor.js:80857:7)
    at refreshChildComponents (vendor.js:79641:5)
    at refreshView (vendor.js:79893:7)
```

Comment: For me, the examples on the Angular Material docs work just fine. What browser do you use? Also, with v15 Angular migrated to the MDC components. Can you try using `MatLegacyMenuModule` instead of `MatMenuModule`?

Comment: I tested latest Chrome, Firefox and Safari, without any issues.

Comment: That's a good question.
`import {MatLegacyMenuModule as MatMenuModule} from "@angular/material/legacy-menu";` has the same error.
Also, the menu is working fine on my browser on the material page. And I'm using Chrome